# How can I make a string type into numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

This is a string-typed numpy array.

```
    '[[-0.44547156 -0.45989361 -0.54462862 -0.77093382 -0.42889501 -0.46236286\n  -0.58319129 -0.56385354 -0.58254861 -0.7476285 ]\n [-0.09561464  0.00522743  0.01977207 -0.71317843 -0.73268128  0.01925189\n  -0.04707032 -0.44227692 -0.06843101 -0.80253451]\n [-0.13276529 -0.22165378  0.08195758 -0.06191557 -0.22300162  0.09476953\n  -0.71540623  0.35323137 -0.26945605 -0.006015  ]\n [ 0.36005916  0.66788728  0.21763805  0.54523638  0.13773763 -0.04109221\n   0.33481649  0.02811258 -0.01340615  0.52465671]]'
```

How can I convert it back to numpy array like

```
    array([[-0.44547156, -0.45989361, -0.54462862, -0.77093382, -0.42889501,
    -0.46236286, -0.58319129, -0.56385354, -0.58254861, -0.7476285 ],
   [-0.09561464,  0.00522743,  0.01977207, -0.71317843, -0.73268128,
     0.01925189, -0.04707032, -0.44227692, -0.06843101, -0.80253451],
   [-0.13276529, -0.22165378,  0.08195758, -0.06191557, -0.22300162,
     0.09476953, -0.71540623,  0.35323137, -0.26945605, -0.006015  ],
   [ 0.36005916,  0.66788728,  0.21763805,  0.54523638,  0.13773763,
    -0.04109221,  0.33481649,  0.02811258, -0.01340615,  0.52465671]])
```

Comment: With a lot of editing - split on the newline, remove the brackets, split on spaces, etc.  And hope the string doesn't include ellipses.  Better yet - don't use this format as a way of saving and/or transferring an array.

Comment: @alexbclay. Nice find

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I need to do numpy operation and store it in the database. Then I need to restore the numpy array from the database and use it in the next operation. In this case, can you recommend some way to transform the numpy array other than string?

Comment: @S.joo. A binary format would be more compact, and could be turned into an array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use string replace to reformat it back to proper list format, then use eval to convert it to list, and then use numpy to get it back to an array

```
str_val = str_val.replace('\n', '').replace('  ',' ').replace('  ', ' ').replace('[ ', '[').replace(' ]', ']').replace(' ', ', ')

back_to_array = np.array(eval(str_val))
```

Comment: None of those replacements seem necessary, and eval is not the best way to go

Comment: @MadPhysicist did you try it? they're necessary to get the eval function to work

Comment: Only inserting commas is necessary. `ast.literal_eval` is generally preferable

Comment: You can use various Label Encoding or one Hot encoding techniques as well

Comment: The best answer is the one that @MadPhysicist flagged this as a duplicate of. I tried that method though on this specific string and it did not work so I came up with something hacky. Eval is definitely not good practice to use though so I wouldn't recommend my answer for any other case.